# What is error for when install psycopg2==2.7.*?

Tags: python, django, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04, heroku-cli

[pip3 install psycop2==2.7.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fp0q.png)

I try to install Django project on a live server but when I install the package I am getting error! pip install psycopg2==2.7.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to install "headers" for C extension. In this case you should install `libpq-dev`

`sudo apt install libpq-dev`